# Message while booting : “can't allocate mem resource [0xc0000000-0xbfffffff]”

Tags: linux, boot, powerpc

I get the following message on the console every time the Linux kernel boots:

```
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 0: can't allocate mem resource [0xc0000000-0xbfffffff]
```

Is this an error message? What causes this message? I am using Linux 2.6 kernel running on PowerPC (P2020).

Updating the question with the output of lspci and content of /proc/iomem

`lspci`:

```
0000:00:00.0 Class 0604: Unknown device 1957:0070 (rev 20)
0000:01:00.0 Class 0200: Unknown device 14e4:1692 (rev 01)
0001:02:00.0 Class 0604: Unknown device 1957:0070 (rev 20)
0001:03:00.0 Class 0200: Unknown device 14e4:1692 (rev 01)
```

`/proc/iomem`:

```
a0000000-bfffffff : /pcie@ffe09000
a0000000-bfffffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
a0000000-a000ffff : 0000:01:00.0
a0000000-a000ffff : tg3
c0000000-dfffffff : /pcie@ffe0a000
c0000000-dfffffff : PCI Bus 0001:03
c0000000-c000ffff : 0001:03:00.0
c0000000-c000ffff : tg3
ffe04500-ffe04507 : serial
ffe04600-ffe04607 : serial
ffe07000-ffe07fff : spi
ffe24000-ffe24fff : ethernet
ffe24520-ffe2453f : mdio
ffe25000-ffe25fff : ethernet
```

Comment: This is a weird memory range, it is in reverse order. It seems there's a pci device which the kernel can't configure properly. It might be caused by a number of reasons, e.g. a PnP issue, a kernel bug, mobo firmware bug etc. Is there any device not working properly? Output of `dmesg`, `lspci` and `/proc/iomem` could help more.

Comment: @forcefsck : Thanks a lot...i will get the dmesg, lspci, /proc/iomem message.. :)

Comment: @forcefsck : updated with the outputs :)

Comment: Do you have any idea what device 0:00:00.0 is? There might be a clue in `/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0`. What exact kernel version are you running, compiled how/by whom?

Comment: Not familiar with ppc, but the listings provided are too short to be complete. Also, 1957:0070 exists in pci.ids and shouldn't be listed as "Unknown device". What is the severity of this, just the warning? Is something not working as expected? Sometimes the kernel can't configure a device until a proper driver is loaded at a later stage. You need to provide distribution and kernel info (`uname -a`) and anything else you think it might be related.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you included the machine's specifics.
0xc000_0000 is the default load address of most Linux distributions but it seems you are using a custom Linux build because you are assigning 0xc000_0000 as PCI address space. Do you have a valid device tree installed? Or do you have Open Firmware?